# How to reload the data of the past few days from Firebase to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase to collect event data from my apps, and integrated my Firebase project to BigQuery. Everyday I download daily data from BigQuery to my database. But a few days ago, due to the expiry of my credit card (even Firebase is not charging anything from my card yet), seems like the services stopped. so today I found that I am missing 2 days of data (8-9 May). Is there any possible ways for me to retrieve back those data? Thanks!

Comment: After changing your payment method, did you actually have to re-link Firebase Analytics to BigQuery?

Comment: I've found the same issue after a payment change and the missing data hasn't been imported. Just mentioning to show this issue is still around.

Answer (score -2):

Can you check if you can find the data for the two days and load them as batch instead using dataflow?

Comment: Hi Sammy,
Thanks for your response. Could you please let me know how can I do as you suggested? Thanks

Comment: Full disclosure, I haven't worked on Firebase. What I'm suggesting is that as in case of PubSub streaming, if data is not published, it is stored as logs, which can be exported to say, Cloud Storage and subsequently loaded as a batch (with any modification to edit Load timestamps) to Big Query.